# Set DataGridView column Width on HTML/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

so i'm bounding my `DataGrid` with some data from an sql query, when I show it everything looks fine, all the data/columns/rows are there.
Now what I want to do is set fixed width to certain columns ( Name, Email, Address) and if the text excedes that width, i want it to be hidden. I've seen a lot of ways to change the width in tables, but this doesn't work with `DGV`.
I also tried `DataGridView1.Columns[1].Width()` but `DGV.Columns` doesn't have a width option.

I'm not adding any code because its a general questions, if you have any examples, that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Columns does not have width property but Cells have it. you can set it at cell level.

```
TestGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width
```

Use `TestGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text` property to get value of the cell and you write logic to check if it exceeds the specified width.